Можно уже и я свою книгу почитаю?
Нужна ли запятая после слова "Можно" в вопросе:
Можно уже и я свою книгу почитаю?

Здесь возможны варианты:
(1) Можно уже и я свою книгу почитаю?
(2) Можно, уже и я свою книгу почитаю?
Пояснение

Частотным будет вариант (1), но это базовый вариант.

Согласно «Русской грамматике» под ред. Н.Ю. Шведовой, можно в данном случае является частицей и не требует постановки знаков препинания.

Вариант (2) используется в том случае, если нужно подчеркнуть просьбу, выделив "можно" ударением. Тогда оно приобретает значение вводности.  Сравнить: Может быть, уже и я свою книгу почитаю?

Об этом есть информация у Грамоты:
   № 288255
   Здравствуйте! Рассматриваю следующие предложения: 1) 
   Можно сделать копию паспорта? 2) Можно я сделаю копию 
   паспорта? 3) Можно мне сделать копию паспорта? 
   Предложение 1) является безличным, 3) безличное с 
   дательным субъекта, в то время как 2) - определенно- 
   личное. Мой вопрос по поводу основы "можно", выделяется 
   ли она запятыми в 2) и 3)? Какая стилистическая/ 
   прагматическая разница в их употреблении? Спасибо!

    ОТВЕТ. В первом и третьем предложениях обособлять слово 
    можно не следует. Во втором предложении обособление 
    факультативно (возможно).


Также отметим, что в обоих случаях можно относится ко всему предложению (является детерминантом), и в этой позиции  обособление как возможно, так и нет.

Примечание. Заданное предложение по своей структуре может иметь иронический характер. Тогда обособление вполне возможно.

Можно сказать, можно подумать - вводные сочетания. Можно не вводное, запятой не требует.
